# Compiling error in returning a value

Tags: vba, excel, compiler-errors

I have a problem:

```
    Public Sub ChangeRow(Column As String, Value As String, id As Integer)
For i = 4 To 15
    For Each rw In Worksheets(i).Rows
        If Worksheets(i).Range("A" & rw.row).Value = id Then
        Dim row As Integer
        **row = getRow(id, i)**
        MsgBox (row)

            If Worksheets(i).Range(Column & rw.row).Value <> Value Then
                Worksheets(i).Range(Column & rw.row) = Value
            End If
            Exit For
        End If
    Next rw
Next i
End Sub

Function getRow(id As Integer, Sheet As Integer) As Integer
    For Each rw In Worksheets(Sheet).Rows
        If Worksheets(Sheet).Range("A" & rw.row).Value = id Then
            getRow = rw.row
        End If
    Next rw
End Function
```

Change Row Works fine... its just when I add 'row = getRow(id, i)' to the mix it throws a ByRef mismatch error??

Comment: You don't declare `i` in the `ChangeRow`. Try adding `Dim i as Integer` in that one.

Comment: Oh! Thanks that works. I guess that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great example as to why using `Option Explicit` is a great practice.

Add `Option Explicit` to the *very top* of your worksheet module, outside your macro.

This forces you to declare all variables used in your subs, and also can help catch typos in your variable names.

This would catch that `i` is not declared.  What's therefore happening is VBA/Excel by default will set `i` to be `Variant`.

Then, when you hit `row = getRow(id, i)`, you're basically passing `row = getRow([integer], [Variant])`.  But that sub is expecting `getRow([integer],[integer])`...hence your `Type Mismatch` error.

So, as mentioned, just do `Dim i as Integer` at the top of the `ChangeRow` sub.

(or, for long run VBA use `Long` instead of `Integer`).

Answer (score -1):

In the function, you need to declare "Sheet" as Worksheet object

```
Function getRow(id As Integer, Sheet As Worksheet) As Integer
```

Comment: 'Sheet' is just the number. The problem was with 'i' not being Declared.